# show data from sql server in blackberry using .Net

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, blackberry

i want to ask about development in blackberry. I have background in .Net winform.
If i want to develop an application to show data from Ms.SQL server 2008 database in blackberry. what should i learn and what should i do ? thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to simply create a web application for the BlackBerry, learning ASP.NET (including MVC) would be the best idea. You'd have to make sure you designed for the BlackBerry browser.

If you want to create a native BlackBerry application, you'll have to pick up Java. On top of that, I'd learn WCF so that you can provide a Web Service front end for your data.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to expose the database directly, you can create an [ADO.NET Data Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/bb931106.aspx) with Linq-to-SQL in about 5 minutes.